# nginx point subdomain to subfolder

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want http://blog.domain.com/ to point to http://www.domain.com/blog

Just a notice, **not** to redirect to that location, but just point to it.
Also **/blog** is not a folder. It could be blog.php for example

So when I navigate to http://blog.domain.com, the website display's content from http://www.domain.com/blog

What I tried so far:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name blog.domain.com;

  rewrite ^/blog(.*) http://blog.domain.com/$1 permanent;    
}
```

The result is nginx returning **404 not found** error.

Comment: Note that adding "permanent" turns this into a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid regex because I'm terrible at it. Perhaps try:

```
  return 301 http://www.example.com/blog$request_uri;
```

[Pitfalls - Nginx Community](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites)

Would setting `root` to the directory that serves www.example.com/blog perform the function you are looking for?

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name blog.domain.com;
  root /path/to/blog;
}
```

Comment: This will redirect the browser, not show the content from the folder on the root of the domain.

Comment: Okay, I'm not clear - the question is how to display www.example.com/blog at blog.example.com? Just set `index` to desired home directory.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Forgot to mention you in above comment, where I also mistakenly stated `index` directive when I meant `root`.

Comment: Your new answer looks pretty good actually. Better than a rewrite rule.

Comment: /blog is a url, not a path. /blog is dynamically generated from within the application logic. Therefore there is no /var/www/domain/blog path.

Comment: Isn't 301 a redirect, which he specifically said he does not want?

Answer (score -1):

Your rewrite syntax is the wrong way around. You want to rewrite the root to the subfolder. In that rule you are rewriting the /blog folder, which isn't what you want.

In `.htaccess` the rule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Convert that into your nginx format.

Comment: I am using nginx, not Apache.

Comment: @mallix I know you are. Did you read what I wrote? The last line. Convert that into ngix format. I'm not here to do your job for you, I'm sure a simple conversion should be within your skillset.

Comment: Of course it is. I totally missed the last line.

Comment: In any case, this gives me an nginx not found response.